# Adding constraints in a constrained problem

Tags: calculus, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider a simplified version of a problem I am looking at:
$$\min_{x, y, z, t_1, t_2, t_3} x - x^2 - y + y^2 - z + z^2 + t_1$$
subject to:
$$ -x + x^2 \leq a + t_1$$
$$ -y + y^2 \leq b - t_2$$
$$ -z + z^2 \leq c - t_3$$
$$ t_1 = t_2 + t_3$$
$$ 0 \leq t_1, t_2, t_3 \leq d$$
where $a$ is known, $b + c = d$, but $b$ and $c$ are unknown.  Given the setup, I am wondering if it is valid to reduce the constraints to:
$$ -x + x^2 \leq a + t_1$$
$$ -y + y^2 -z + z^2 \leq d - t_1$$
$$ 0 \leq t_1 \leq d$$
so the exact values of $b$ and $c$ are not required and $t_2$ and $t_3$ can be ignored.  Is this wishful thinking?

Comment: It might look simpler if you shift the origin by adding $\frac12$ to $x,y,z$ and $\frac14$ to $a,b,c$ (and the objective function).

Comment: (After that, you might want transform by taking square roots and restricting to the first octant.)

Comment: Does the answer help ?

Comment: @callculus When I write out the Lagrangian's FOC I have the multipliers on $y$ and $z$ being equal (via the equality constraint) which led me to my question.  I completely agree in general this is not a good idea.

Comment: If you've established via a Lagrangian argument that you can eliminate one or more of the inequalities, then yes, that's fine. I haven't done that here myself, so I can't tell you if your particular simplification is valid.

Comment: Note that your objective function is not convex, so this is technically not a convex optimization problem. I had removed the convex-optimization tag, but decided to replace it, because your constraints *are* convex. So simply manipulating the constraints falls within the scope of convex optimization.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is **not** a good idea to add **in**equalities.

Suppose $b=0.5, c=1, y=z=0.5$ and $t_2=t_3=1$.

The inequality $-y + y^2 -z + z^2 \leq d - t_1$ holds and

$ -y + y^2 \leq b - t_2$ doesn´t hold.